# How to compile SQL in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00942

I have a SQL query that has error.

When I execute it i get  `ORA-00942: Table or view does not exist`.

**I don't know which table is giving me the error.**

I do know that some SQL Editors offer compilation of SQL and highlight the part that has error. is it possible in oracle sql developer?

Answer (score 2):

Try the ye ol' Oracle SQL*Plus

```
SQL> select * from dasd
  2  union 
  3  select 1 from dual
  4  /
select * from dasd
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

---

If you want to know if it's possible in SQL developer - it depends. If it's a stored procedure, double-clicking on the error message in the Log -> Compiler messages should show the approximate location of the error. If you're running in SQL Worksheet, then unfortunately, it's not possible.